# detect when screen turns off in windows phone

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7

Is there any way to detect when the screen turns off in the windows phone? It is possible to make the application run when this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set `ApplicationIdleDecectionMode` to `Enabled` and handle `Obscured` and `Unobscured` events of root frame:

```
Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Enabled;
      var rootFrame = App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
      if(rootFrame != null)
      {
        rootFrame.Obscured += new EventHandler<ObscuredEventArgs>(rootFrame_Obscured);
        rootFrame.Unobscured += new EventHandler(rootFrame_Unobscured);
      }
```

Look more at this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2010/11/01/running-a-windows-phone-application-under-the-lock-screen.aspx)

Comment: It's good practice to include the important code samples, for future references. The link might die, or be 404'd when someone reads your answer.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen thanks for comment, I always want to make my answers more useful)