# Handle Screen Off/On Event

Tags: c#, screen, win-universal-app

I am searching for an event with that I get weather the screen is turned on or off. In Android there is this nice BroadcastReceiver. Is there anything like that in UWP-Apps?

Kind regards

Comment: [Detect when screen turns off in windows phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887134/detect-when-screen-turns-off-in-windows-phone)

Comment: The link you posted is only for windows-phone-7 and almost no stuff from then is usable now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if display is turned off by windows power management](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530968/check-if-display-is-turned-off-by-windows-power-management)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, its the system level behavior and there is no bridge like BroadcastReceiver to deliver such message into the app. There used to be one for Windows Phone Silverlight but not available on Windows Universal App.

If you simply wants to keep the screen on, try this: [RequestActive | requestActive method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.display.displayrequest.requestactive.aspx)

Comment: well that's crap..thanks for your help. Hopefully this will be implemented at some time..

Comment: You can file feedback with the Windows 10 feedback app (there is a "Developer Platform" option). Please include the scenario where you want to know if the screen is off (eg, is your app in the foreground and wants to keep running, or is it a background task, etc)